# how to set the table's row background color in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

i used

```
mycurrent_row.setAttribute("bgcolor", "#EEF4EA");
```

it worked for both firefox and chrome.but no color was set in ie

i use

```
mycurrent_row.setAttribute("bgcolor", "#EEF4EA");
mycurrent_row.bgcolor = "#EEF4EA";
```

it neither work.

How can i set the row's color in IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute is named `bgColor`, not `bgcolor`, but you should rather use the [backgroundColor CSS property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for styling instead of [the deprecated HTML attribute bgColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
mycurrent_row.style.backgroundColor = "#EEF4EA";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the style inline

```
mycurrent_row.setAttribute("style", "background:#EEF4EA");
```